# Specific tpl-file for creating a node => node--type--create.tpl.php

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

`page--node--edit.tpl.php` works just fine when you want to create a specific template for editing a node, but is there a similar syntax for creating files? I've tried `page--node--create.tpl.php` or `node--type--create.tpl.php`, but nothing worked... Does it even exists? Or how can I create a specific template for creating content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* using Drupal's `page--` theme overrides would work on a content creation page if the file is called:

```
page--node--add--article.tpl.php
```

Where the type of the node is `article`.

Remember to clear Drupal's caches when you've created the file, and also make sure that this template is part of the active administration theme (although you've probably already done this as if you hadn't `page--node--edit.tpl.php` wouldn't work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My content-type is called `fiche`, and according to you, it should be `page--node--fiche--add.tpl.php`, right? But unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: Haha, I found it!! You weren't that far from it. I just needed to change the order of the words. The working page is called `page--node--add--fiche.tpl.php` where `fiche` is my content type. But for some reason, no content is showing...

Comment: Doh sorry about that I mixed up the path parts! There's an excellent [article here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) which gives a lot of information on template suggestions for Drupal 7, it might be a good place to have a look :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you happen to know why I got a blank page as result? I can type some default HTML, but no variables of Drupal are accepted (`$content`, `$links`,...)

Comment: Ok, found it myself :-) apparently, I you are using a `page--node--add--article.tpl.php` page, you also need a `page--node.tpl.php` and a `page--node--add.tpl.php`-page. Thanks for your help, again!